# Whats wrong with the way I am referencing these rails params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to rails, trying to figure out my way around it but have hit a road block,

I am trying to display all of the movies from a database that are a certain rating, based on checkboxes the user checks. Here is the form for the checkboxes and movie table

```
-#  This file is app/views/movies/index.html.haml
%h1 All Movies
= form_tag movies_path, :id => "ratings_form", :method => :get do
  Include:
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]",  1, rating
  = submit_tag 'Refresh'
%table#movies
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Movie Title
      %th Rating
      %th Release Date
      %th More Info
  %tbody
    - @movies.each do |movie|
      %tr
        %td= movie.title 
        %td= movie.rating
        %td= movie.release_date
        %td= link_to "More about #{movie.title}", movie_path(movie)

= link_to 'Add new movie', new_movie_path
```

And this is the movie controller

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    id = params[:id] # retrieve movie ID from URI route
    @movie = Movie.find(id) # look up movie by unique ID
    # will render app/views/movies/show.<extension> by default
  end

    def index
        @all_ratings = Movie.all_ratings
    @movies = Movie.where(:ratings)
    end

  def new
    # default: render 'new' template
  end

  def create
    @movie = Movie.create!(params[:movie])
    flash[:notice] = "#{@movie.title} was successfully created."
    redirect_to movies_path
  end

  def edit
    @movie = Movie.find params[:id]
  end
  def update
    @movie = Movie.find params[:id]
    @movie.update_attributes!(params[:movie])
    flash[:notice] = "#{@movie.title} was successfully updated."
    redirect_to movie_path(@movie)
  end

  def destroy
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @movie.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Movie '#{@movie.title}' deleted."
    redirect_to movies_path
  end
end
```

As it is I cannot figure out why there are no movies showing, there are definitely some in the database. I feel like the there is nothing in the :ratings but am not sure of any other way to reference them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First move column ratings to rating.

```
 = form_tag movies_path, :id => "ratings_form", :method => :get do
   Include:
   - Movie.all_ratings.each do |rating|
     = rating
     = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]",  0, rating
   = submit_tag 'Refresh'
```

And in controller you find in where array of rating

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @movies = Movie.where(rating: params[:ratings].keys)
  end

  #....
end
```

One thing - before you send ratings params you get empty array!
Simple resolve this problem by:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:ratings].present?
      @movies = Movie.where(rating: params[:ratings].keys)
    else
      @movies = Movie.all
    end
  end

  #....
end
```

or do this in scope in model (it's better option!)

Will be great if somebody add more elegant solution :)

Comment: Okay so this seemed to get me somewhere but now I am getting the error "SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: G: SELECT "movies".* FROM "movies"  WHERE (G)" when I click the refresh button on the form. It loads fine the first time but if change the checkboxes and refresh it seems to crash.

Comment: I had a typo in my model and was missing a ":", the code you posted works! Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome :)

Have you done rake db:migrate and have you got migration with movies?

Please, restart server after migrate.